# Помощь в создании кнопки работающей на всех страницах сайта

Tags: javascript, php, html5

уже не один день бьюсь над работой кнопки для установки приложения pwa
Опишу подробно
Данный ниже код вызывает модальное окно для установки приложения pwa этот код размещен в head

```
<script  type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@pwabuilder/pwainstall"></script>
```

const ref = document.getElementById("installComponent");ref.getInstalledStatus();

кнопка работает всё нормально, но только на главной странице сайта, на других страницах отображение происходит кнопки но она де срабатывает, помогите пожалуйста.

```js
<script  type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@pwabuilder/pwainstall"></script>
<script async defer> const ref = document.getElementById("installComponent");ref.getInstalledStatus(); </script>
<pwa-install id="installComponent" style="z-index: 999999999;top:20px;position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px;"></pwa-install>
```

Comment: #installComponent точно есть на всех страницах сайта?

Comment: да этот есть на всех страницах сайта, если у вас на сайте есть manifest.json вы можете проверить работу данного примера

Comment: https://components.pwabuilder.com/component/install_pwa  информация с этого сайта